# Отправка уведомлений с сайта в систему MacOS

Tags: php, javascript, macos, safari

На некоторых сайтах видел всплывающее окно о том, чтобы отправлять новости в центр уведомлений *MacOS*. Как такое можно реализовать? Пытался найти информации по этому поводу в интернете, но или плохо/неправильно искал, или этой информации действительно не много.

Answer (score 0):

Шаринг по англоязычным ресурсам привел меня к решению проблемы, поэтому я оставлю тут код работы. Мало ли кому пригодится(работает только в *Safari* и *Chrome* на *MacOs*, под *iOS* не нашел нотификатора)

```js
function notify() {
  // Проверка поддерживаемости браузером
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("Ваш браузер не поддерживает уведомления");
  }

  // Проверка разрешения на отправку 
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    var notification = new Notification("Hello World!");
  }

  // Если разрешения нет, то запрашиваем его
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // Если пользователь разрешил, то создаем уведомление 
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hello World!");
      }
    });
  }

  //Если нам отказали, то не  достаем больше
}Notification.requestPermission();function spawnNotification(theBody,theIcon,theTitle) {
  var options = {
      body: theBody,
      icon: theIcon
  }
  var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="notify()">Клик!</button>
```